# scala trait (or abstract class): set a timestamp variable (or parameter) at instantiation of instance

Tags: scala

I have a trait and several case classes inherit from it. Something like this:

```
sealed trait Event
case class Meeting(name: String)
case class Call(number: String)
```

I want to add a timestamp to each event instance. The idea is to set the timestamp during the instantiation for each class instance. It's easy to put it in each case class definition. But I wonder if I could somehow put it in `Event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare it in the trait

```
  sealed trait Event {
    val time = LocalDateTime.now()
  }
  case class Meeting(name: String) extends Event
  case class Call(number: String) extends Event
```

Answer (score 2):

Given *case class* semantics (`.equals`, `.hashCode`, `.toString`, etc.), you might prefer this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

sealed trait Event {
  val time: LocalDateTime
}

final case class Meeting(name: String, override val time: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now())
extends Event

final case class Call(number: String, override val time: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now())
extends Event
```

Admittedly, this is not quite so elegant, but it will work more consistently. For example, consider this *Scala REPL* session:

```
scala> val m1 = Meeting("Some meeting")
m1: Meeting = Meeting(Some meeting,2017-10-27T17:15:37.389)

scala> val m2 = Meeting("Some meeting")
m2: Meeting = Meeting(Some meeting,2017-10-27T17:15:46.829)

scala> m1 == m2
res0: Boolean = false
```

`m1` and `m2` aren't equal because they have different start times.

You can also bring the full power of case classes to bear, with pattern matching on times, etc., while also treating `Meeting` and `Call` as `Event`s. For example:

```
val events: List[Event] = //...

// Filter events that occurred in the last week.
val oneWeekAgo = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7)
val recent = events.filter(_.time.isAfter(oneWeekAgo))

// Convert to log messages.
val msg = recent.map {
  case Meeting(n, t) => s"Meeting $n, held on ${t.toString}"
  case Call(n, t) => s"Telephone call to $n, made on ${t.toString}"
}
```

This version is also easier to test, as explicit start times can be included.